# Adding CSS class in form that posts to PHP breaks query

Tags: php, css, forms, mysqli

I am a beginner to coding... Something strange happens when I enter a CSS class to a form that posts data to same php file that executes mysqli query. Everything goes well until I add  to the form. When I do this, I don't get an error, but browser reads: `search.php?submitted=true&category=firstname&criteria=hassan&submitted=Submit.` I also don't get any results back.

When I don't have the css class added, it works fine, url doesn't read the above and database results come back. Any help as to why this happens and what I can do to fix it?

Apologies in advance for strange way of adding css. Using purecss.io but import from yahoo cdn doesn't work, also uploading to server doesn't work. Only way I get it to work is by adding the css code directly into file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>pageName</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
background-color: #ADD8E6;
border: 1px solid black;
font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;
}
th {
text-align: left;
}

.pure-form input[type=text],.pure-form input[type=password],.pure-form input[type=email],.pure-form input[type=url],.pure-form input[type=date],.pure-form input[type=month],.pure-form input[type=time],.pure-form input[type=datetime],.pure-form input[type=datetime-local],.pure-form input[type=week],.pure-form input[type=number],.pure-form input[type=search],.pure-form input[type=tel],.pure-form input[type=color],.pure-form select,.pure-form textarea{padding:.5em .6em;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ccc;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;border-radius:4px;vertical-align:middle;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.pure-form input:not([type]){padding:.5em .6em;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ccc;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.pure-form input[type=color]{padding:.2em .5em}.pure-form input[type=text]:focus,.pure-form input[type=password]:focus,.pure-form input[type=email]:focus,.pure-form input[type=url]:focus,.pure-form input[type=date]:focus,.pure-form input[type=month]:focus,.pure-form input[type=time]:focus,.pure-form input[type=datetime]:focus,.pure-form input[type=datetime-local]:focus,.pure-form input[type=week]:focus,.pure-form input[type=number]:focus,.pure-form input[type=search]:focus,.pure-form input[type=tel]:focus,.pure-form input[type=color]:focus,.pure-form select:focus,.pure-form textarea:focus{outline:0;border-color:#129FEA}.pure-form input:not([type]):focus{outline:0;border-color:#129FEA}.pure-form input[type=file]:focus,.pure-form input[type=radio]:focus,.pure-form input[type=checkbox]:focus{outline:thin solid #129FEA;outline:1px auto #129FEA}.pure-form .pure-checkbox,.pure-form .pure-radio{margin:.5em 0;display:block}.pure-form input[type=text][disabled],.pure-form input[type=password][disabled],.pure-form input[type=email][disabled],.pure-form input[type=url][disabled],.pure-form input[type=date][disabled],.pure-form input[type=month][disabled],.pure-form input[type=time][disabled],.pure-form input[type=datetime][disabled],.pure-form input[type=datetime-local][disabled],.pure-form input[type=week][disabled],.pure-form input[type=number][disabled],.pure-form input[type=search][disabled],.pure-form input[type=tel][disabled],.pure-form input[type=color][disabled],.pure-form select[disabled],.pure-form textarea[disabled]{cursor:not-allowed;background-color:#eaeded;color:#cad2d3}.pure-form input:not([type])[disabled]{cursor:not-allowed;background-color:#eaeded;color:#cad2d3}.pure-form input[readonly],.pure-form select[readonly],.pure-form textarea[readonly]{background-color:#eee;color:#777;border-color:#ccc}.pure-form input:focus:invalid,.pure-form textarea:focus:invalid,.pure-form select:focus:invalid{color:#b94a48;border-color:#e9322d}.pure-form input[type=file]:focus:invalid:focus,.pure-form input[type=radio]:focus:invalid:focus,.pure-form input[type=checkbox]:focus:invalid:focus{outline-color:#e9322d}.pure-form select{height:2.25em;border:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#fff}.pure-form select[multiple]{height:auto}.pure-form label{margin:.5em 0 .2em}.pure-form fieldset{margin:0;padding:.35em 0 .75em;border:0}.pure-form legend{display:block;width:100%;padding:.3em 0;margin-bottom:.3em;color:#333;border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5}.pure-form-stacked input[type=text],.pure-form-stacked input[type=password],.pure-form-stacked input[type=email],.pure-form-stacked input[type=url],.pure-form-stacked input[type=date],.pure-form-stacked input[type=month],.pure-form-stacked input[type=time],.pure-form-stacked input[type=datetime],.pure-form-stacked input[type=datetime-local],.pure-form-stacked input[type=week],.pure-form-stacked input[type=number],.pure-form-stacked input[type=search],.pure-form-stacked input[type=tel],.pure-form-stacked input[type=color],.pure-form-stacked input[type=file],.pure-form-stacked select,.pure-form-stacked label,.pure-form-stacked textarea{display:block;margin:.25em 0}.pure-form-stacked input:not([type]){display:block;margin:.25em 0}.pure-form-aligned input,.pure-form-aligned textarea,.pure-form-aligned select,.pure-form-aligned .pure-help-inline,.pure-form-message-inline{display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;vertical-align:middle}.pure-form-aligned textarea{vertical-align:top}.pure-form-aligned .pure-control-group{margin-bottom:.5em}.pure-form-aligned .pure-control-group label{text-align:right;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:10em;margin:0 1em 0 0}.pure-form-aligned .pure-controls{margin:1.5em 0 0 11em}.pure-form input.pure-input-rounded,.pure-form .pure-input-rounded{border-radius:2em;padding:.5em 1em}.pure-form .pure-group fieldset{margin-bottom:10px}.pure-form .pure-group input,.pure-form .pure-group textarea{display:block;padding:10px;margin:0 0 -1px;border-radius:0;position:relative;top:-1px}.pure-form .pure-group input:focus,.pure-form .pure-group textarea:focus{z-index:3}.pure-form .pure-group input:first-child,.pure-form .pure-group textarea:first-child{top:1px;border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;margin:0}.pure-form .pure-group input:first-child:last-child,.pure-form .pure-group textarea:first-child:last-child{top:1px;border-radius:4px;margin:0}.pure-form .pure-group input:last-child,.pure-form .pure-group textarea:last-child{top:-2px;border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;margin:0}.pure-form .pure-group button{margin:.35em 0}.pure-form .pure-input-1{width:100%}.pure-form .pure-input-2-3{width:66%}.pure-form .pure-input-1-2{width:50%}.pure-form .pure-input-1-3{width:33%}.pure-form .pure-input-1-4{width:25%}.pure-form .pure-help-inline,.pure-form-message-inline{display:inline-block;padding-left:.3em;color:#666;vertical-align:middle;font-size:.875em}.pure-form-message{display:block;color:#666;font-size:.875em}@media only screen and (max-width :480px){.pure-form button[type=submit]{margin:.7em 0 0}.pure-form input:not([type]),.pure-form input[type=text],.pure-form input[type=password],.pure-form input[type=email],.pure-form input[type=url],.pure-form input[type=date],.pure-form input[type=month],.pure-form input[type=time],.pure-form input[type=datetime],.pure-form input[type=datetime-local],.pure-form input[type=week],.pure-form input[type=number],.pure-form input[type=search],.pure-form input[type=tel],.pure-form input[type=color],.pure-form label{margin-bottom:.3em;display:block}.pure-group input:not([type]),.pure-group input[type=text],.pure-group input[type=password],.pure-group input[type=email],.pure-group input[type=url],.pure-group input[type=date],.pure-group input[type=month],.pure-group input[type=time],.pure-group input[type=datetime],.pure-group input[type=datetime-local],.pure-group input[type=week],.pure-group input[type=number],.pure-group input[type=search],.pure-group input[type=tel],.pure-group input[type=color]{margin-bottom:0}.pure-form-aligned .pure-control-group label{margin-bottom:.3em;text-align:left;display:block;width:100%}.pure-form-aligned .pure-controls{margin:1.5em 0 0}.pure-form .pure-help-inline,.pure-form-message-inline,.pure-form-message{display:block;font-size:.75em;padding:.2em 0 .8em}}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MEMBERS SEARCH</h1>
<form class="pure-form">
<form method="post" action="search.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>
<label> Search Category:
<select name="category">
<option value="firstname">First NAME</option>
<option value="lastname">Last NAME</option>
</select>
</label>
<label> Search Criteria:<input type="text" name="criteria" /></label>
<input type="submit" name="submitted" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
// connect to the DB
include('connect.php');
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category']);
$criteria = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['criteria']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE firstname LIKE '%" . $criteria   ."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows results found";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>
<table>
 <tr>
 <td width="300" ><font face="Arial Black" size="2"><?php echo $row['firstname']?> <?php echo $row['lastname']?></font></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr>
 <td width="100"><b>Licence #</b></td>
<td width="3">:</td>
 <td width="120"><?php echo $row['licencenr']?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td width="100"><b>Birthday</b></td>
<td width="3">:</td>
 <td width="120"><?php echo $row['birth']?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td width="100"><b>Age</b></td>
<td width="3">:</td>
 <td width="120"><?php echo $row['age']?></td>
 </tr>
 <td width="120"> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br>
<?php
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using two `<form>` tags

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...

instead of adding

```
<form class="pure-form">
```

i deleted

```
<form class="pure-form">
```

and changed

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
```

to

```
<form method="post" class="pure-form" action="search.php">
```